# Play framework 60 second delay - extending information in the logs

Tags: scala, playframework, netty, logback

In our **scala/play** application we have a request that usually takes about a second to respond. About 2-4% of the time the requests takes about **61** seconds to respond - and the webproxy timesout the request (504). 61 seconds looks suspiciously like a **timeout**.

I am trying to get more information out of the logs, but they remain silent on these 61 seconds. I have tried setting **play** and **io.netty** to level DEBUG, but have not found anything. A successful response followed by the next request (**1.4** second gap) looks like

```
2017-01-31 13:13:09,931 - [DEBUG] - from com.xxx.api.controllers.Api in monolith-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-34 
new Result created - .. ..
2017-01-31 13:13:11,318 - [DEBUG] - from com.xxx.api.controllers.Api in monolith-
akka.actor.default-dispatcher-34 
Upload media - .. ..
```

An response followed by next request with **61** second gap looks like

```
2017-01-31 13:12:08,624 - [DEBUG] - from com.xxx.api.controllers.Api in monolith-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31 
new Result created - .. ..
2017-01-31 13:13:09,892 - [DEBUG] - from com.xxx.controllers.Api in monolith-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-34 
Upload media - .. ..
```

Has anyone got any suggestions on configuring logback.xml to tell me what is going on between 13:12:08 and 13:13:09.

Comment: Where do you have logs in the code?

Comment: `uploadMedia()` is controller implementation method, referred to from `routes` configuration. _Upload media .._ is the first statement in the method, _new Result created .._ is the last statement in the method.

Comment: Having set level to TRACE on all logs I can find, I have narrowed the delay to the following two lines which indicate the delay is occurring within the Play framework.

`xx:x5:45,640 play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler in netty-event-loop-1 Http request received by netty`
`xx:x6:45,630 play.api.mvc.Action in monolith-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23 Invoking action with request`

Answer (score 0):

I set log level to TRACE in conf/logback.xml, `<logger name="play" level="TRACE" />`

The log shows that the 60 second delay is occurring somewhere within the play framework. I have now reported this as issue [6943](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6943)